# The Votes tab on my own Meta profile is in an odd position

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, meta, tabs

When I visit my own profile in Firefox Aurora 30.0a2, the 'Votes' tab is pushed out of place into a new row. It will appear just below & to the right of whichever tab I have open. If it *is* the tab open, it'll just be all the way to its left, on its own row. If I mouse over any item above it or to its right, funny things happen - it gets pushed around.

It's probably because of the blue boxes beside all those items. But, probably, the site's own run-of-the-mill features shouldn't break its own layout.

[image: dangit votes get back into formation]

Comment: Visit your *reputation* and *responses* tabs. It may help you.

Comment: Clear some of the numbers and all will be good. The dev team never assumed people will just let it grow. :) (@hims056 cough... dupe... cough...)

Comment: Yeah, I can, but hence my saying: the site's features shouldn't break its own layout. :P If they dump extra content in those tabs, they should probably have the tabs _somehow_ be able to handle it.

Comment: I can imagine other ways, such as having a tab row that still looks fine if one of the tabs flows onto the next line. There _are_ ways to handle this OK, so it still looks and works fine, and doesn't look like a bug.